# Associate current_user with json response from API call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, controller

I need to tie the current user with the json response that I am capturing and storing in PostgreSql 9.4. I am using Rails 4. I am able to successfully store the json in a column 'return' of json data type. I have taken measures to create the model associations and updated the schema, and I have a user model with a record but the user_id remains nil in the Document record holding the json return. I list the controller as I'm nearly convinced that my problem is here.

```
require 'alchemyAPI/alchemyapi'
require 'json'

class AlchemyController < ApplicationController

def index
  @documents = Document.all
end

def create
  alchemyapi = AlchemyAPI.new()
  response = alchemyapi.combined('url', params[:q],  {'extract'=>'page-image, title, author, concept' })
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(response)

if 
  Document.create(result: response)
  flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully analyzed and persisted."
  redirect_to action: 'index'
else
  flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully analyzed and persisted."
  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
end
end
```

Comment: Is this question still valid if you've removed references to the problem you mention in the title?

Comment: I know how to use the create controller action in the standard way of passing in params from a form. What I don't know how to do is substitute those parameters for the json return I'm getting back from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was for me to add the current user as depicted in the first two lines of the if block.

```
def create
 alchemyapi = AlchemyAPI.new()
 response = alchemyapi.combined('url', params[:q],  {'extract'=>'page-image, title, author, concept' })
 puts JSON.pretty_generate(response)

if 
 *@user = current_user*
 *@user.documents.create(result: response)*
 flash[:notice] = "Input was successfully analyzed and persisted."
 redirect_to action: 'index'
else
 flash[:error] = "There was a problem analyzing your input."
 redirect_to action: 'index'
end
end
```